# How to create a Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 application Development with Web Service or WCF service?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, embedded

I am using Visual Studio 2008 for Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 application Development but I am not able to add the Web Service or a WCF Service, Can anybody help me out with any solution, or suggest me any other way for developing the application.
The application will be run on Zebra MC3200 Mobile Scanner Device. 
Thank You :)

Comment: What have you tried?  What exceptions did you get?

Comment: I have created a Windows Embedded Compact Project and another WCF Project and I tried to call the WCF from the Url, i am getting all the properties but when i am running the project error throwing  "Cannot connect to Remote Server "

Comment: The remote server has to start before the client attempt to connect.  The best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture the http messages and check status like 200 Done.  Most likely the status is an error in either the 400, or 500 range.